# Highstock export csv based on data grouping (export-data module)

Tags: highcharts

Currently, the export-data module exports all the series data rather than processedXData and processedYData. However, I grouped the series with dataGrouping and I'd like to export only the processed data.

I'm aware that this question has been asked before ([Highstock export csv based on data grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985955/highstock-export-csv-based-on-data-grouping)), but it was in the context of the former export-cvs plugin.

How to modify the 'getDataRows' function in the export-data module for including only the processed data?

Example -> [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/javiermarquez/mahwz4tr/)

```
Highcharts.getJSON("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/usdeur.json",function (data) {
    var chart = Highcharts.stockChart("container", {
      series: [{
          name: "The series",
          data: data,
          dataGrouping: {
            force: true,
            units: [["year", [1]]]
          }
        }
      ]
    });
console.log(chart.getDataRows()); 
  }
);
```

Comment: Does this problem also occur in JSFiddle? If so, it will be much easier if you could send us your code, so that we can also test it.

Comment: @madepiet Question edited :)

Comment: So you would like to export a different chart image than you currently get in the main chart?